# I need help in action forms

Tags: html, forms, action

I am working in HTML and forget how to The action of the form should be null (#).I have been looking through my book and even looking on the web for it can someone point me in the right directions. I have to make a survey for my class and it all need to be null or the form does. thank you so much.

Comment: This question does not make much sense. If you want to prevent the form from getting submitted, then add an onsubmit attribute and set it to return(false).

Comment: Ok my question was The action of the form should be null (#). That is what i have to answer. I forget how to do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to stop a form from submitting is to use JavaScript. If you leave the action blank (`action=""`) or leave it off entirely, then it defaults to the current page. That's probably as close to a null action as you're going to get.

Comment: If you set action to "" or if you do use it, the form will still be posted. Use this with angle brackets. [form onsubmit="return(false);"]